# How to print a triangle whose sides are not equal?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with C++ and decided to try printing geometric shapes to the console. After printing an equilateral triangle, I decided I should try printing a triangle with varying side lengths, so that one is longer / shorter than the other.

I've tried searching the internet for this, but couldn't find any good explanations for it. After failing to do it on my own, I'd appreciate some help. Below is my code for an equilateral triangle:

```
unsigned size{ 5 };
for (int x{ 0 }; x < size; x++) {
    for (int y{ 0 }; y <= x; y++) {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which works and prints:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Issue is, it can't handle the lower side being longer than the left one, for example. How do I go about doing that, so that I can end up with something like...

```
* 
*** 
****
******
********
```

...where the left side and the lower side are not equal?

Comment: Your inner loop needs to depend on something other than x. You'll need to figure out how long each line should be and use that.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to print perfect triangles with asterisks(*). Instead, try using a graphics library and play with pixels.

Comment: @SSG It'll be a reasonable approximation - in fact this is a good way to learn what happens when you play with pixels... without the complex distraction of graphics libraries. Clearly the point of the exercise is to learn how to write algorithms based on mathematical properties, not to literally draw a triangle on screen.

Comment: True. I meant that you should manually calculate pixel coordinates and set pixels to draw the triangles.

Comment: That's indeed the the aim of this. I started with a circle, then a simple triangle, now this, where I got slightly stuck. I think it's a good idea to learn how this works and how to apply the math I learned to code.

Comment: Calculating pixel coordinates would help you learn how actually algorithms and coordinate geometry work in computers. Try some of the well-known algorithms too.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start:

```
void paint_triangle(size_t x, size_t y) {
    size_t Y=1;
    while(Y<=y) std::cout << std::string(x*Y++/y, '*') << "\n";
}
```